# How to disable specific dates in react Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

Is it possible to disable specific dates while selecting specific users in react Datepicker

Comment: to disable date, use [excludeDates](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range-for-one-datepicker-with-disabled-dates-highlighted). but what do you mean "while selecting specific users" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [excludeDates](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-exclude-dates) for this. It's an array of Date objects:

```
<DatePicker
    selected={startDate}
    onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
    excludeDates={[new Date(), subDays(new Date(), 1)]}
    placeholderText="Select a date other than today or yesterday"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the simplest solution is to use `excludeDates` and add `addDays(new Date(), 5)` <-- 5 being the date you want to exclude, to the array, then delete `selectsRange`:

```js
...
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={onChange}
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      excludeDates={[addDays(new Date(), 1), addDays(new Date(), 5), addDays(new Date(), 7), addDays(new Date(), 12) ]}
      //selectsRange
      selectsDisabledDaysInRange
      inline
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: if you want specific dates, then add the date (yyy-MM-dd format) as an argument to Date(), and set the number to 0 -->  `excludeDates={[addDays(new Date("2023-02-15"), 0), addDays(new Date("2023-02-28"), 0)]}`

Answer (score 0):

*Improving Mahesh Samudra's answer*

**While selecting specific users**

I understand from that sentence that you want to disable specific dates for some users, like a role based access

Let's say you keep user data like that

```
user = {
  name: 'ABC',
  email: 'abc@abc.com',
  role: 'Admin' //Admin, User, etc..
};
```

Then you can control your `excludeDates` property like so

```
excludeDates={user.role !== 'Admin' ? [new Date(), subDays(new Date(), 1)] : []}
```

**UPDATE**
You can get user data from your endpoint like that

```
useEffect(() => {
  apiEndpoint
    .then(result => setUser(result.data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}, [])
```

Comment: if the data is static means you are right but what if the user data coming from API endpoint

Comment: Nothing works in react datepicker

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: _Iitalic_**bold**`useEffect(() => {
    const getInvalidDate =async()=>{
        await UserServices.invalidDatesApi(headers,MeetDetails.assign_to)
       .then((res)=>{     
         setInvalidDate(res.data.invalid_dates);
       }) 
    }
    getInvalidDate()
  }, [assignToName]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inValidDate)
  }, [inValidDate]);

  const disableCustomDt = current => {return !inValidDate.includes(current.format("MM/dd/yyyy"));   }

`

Comment: excludeDates={ inValidDate.length > 0 ? [new Date(), disableCustomDt(new Date(), 1)] : []}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable dates just use the react-day-picker library, you just have to pass an array of dates to disable to the disable props or pass an array of object containing the range to disable which is "from" and "to".
i hope this answers your question

```
 `import {DayPicker} from "react-day-picker";
 const disableDates= [new Date(2022/08/2),{from: new Date(2023/05/3),to:new Date(2023/05/8)]

 <DayPicker
 mode='single'
 selected={date}
 onSelect={onSelect}
 initialFocus
 disabled={disabledDates}
 />
`
```